# Is srand(time(NULL)) bad?

Tags: c++, random, srand

In [rand() considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) it is pointed out that `srand(time(NULL))` is bad because `srand` takes an `unsigned int`, but for Microsoft's compiler, `time_t` by default is a 64-bit number, therefore a narrowing conversion happens. However, `time_t` is implementation-defined.

Since I see `srand(time(NULL))` so prevalent (even on this site), should it be discouraged?

Comment: There are better ways of randomizing, why not use them?

Comment: It's about the best you can do in C, or even in C++ 98/03. C++11 added a new `<random>` header with new random number generation capabilities improve the situation substantially.

Comment: While true, Boost has better PRNGs that work in C++98.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Name a few please.

Comment: @user1095108 Start with the functionality declared in the `random` header

Comment: Short answer: Use it in toy programs, don't use it for anything you're going to publish or use for any important application.

Comment: Not for **that** reason - a 32 bit integer that counts seconds will take 136 years to overflow (time_t's are signed, so it's 136/2 starting from 1970, ie 2038; ntp uses/used uint32 from 1900, so 2036).

Answer (score 12):

> Since I see srand(time(NULL)) so prevalent (even on this site), should it be discouraged?

It depends on how you want to use the output from from your generator (in this case, the output of `rand()`).

If you only need a uniform distribution for single runs of your program, then `srand(time(NULL))` is fine. This would be acceptable in a simulation where you only need a uniform distribution of numbers quickly.

If you want to submit a batch job so that multiple instances of your program run at the same time (and are effectively started at the same time), then `srand(time(NULL))` will probably result in one or more instances producing the same random stream.

If you need a secure output, then you should *not* use `srand(time(NULL))` because its often a Linear Congruential Generator (LCG). Joan Boyar taught us how to break them years ago. See [Inferring sequences produced by a linear congruential generator missing low-order bits](http://asterix.cs.gsu.edu/crypto/p129-boyar.pdf).

As for the problem with `time_t`, just fold it to fit the argument expected by `srand` if `time_t` is too large. You might even fold in the process PID so that batch simulation jobs work as intended/expected.

Comment: When `/dev/urandom` is not available, to make the seed harder to guess, and to avoid collisions, Perl mixes the process ID, a stack pointer and the time (preferably seconds + microseconds from gettimeofday).  http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/v5.20.1:/util.c#l4409